# How to set vim as the default Text editor?

Tags: gvim, microsoft-windows

I'm trying to set gVim to be the default text editor on Windows but it won't work. It works with notepad++, editor... but not with Vim. Any ideas how to fix it?

Screenshot: http://prntscr.com/lm069a

I also tried to choose `gvim.exe` with the option that opens the explorer. if I open it it works, but it doesn't save Vim as the default text editor.

Comment: Weird. I already had gVim set as my default editor. I changed it to notepad to test, and now I've got the same problem as you: I can't change it back!

Comment: I think the problem might be that, in Windows 10, `.txt` is a ["protected" file type](https://ardamis.com/2015/12/01/configuring-a-default-application-for-protected-file-types-in-windows-10/). ...although that doesn't explain why you *can* set the default to be notepad++.

Comment: Is this really a problem about Vim? I feel like this question would be better on https://superuser.com/

Comment: @statox Seems like kind of an edge case. The problem as described does appear to be specific to Vim, but at the same time, it looks as though the root issue is more to do with Windows (and how it interacts with the Vim executable) than Vim itself.

Answer (score 4):

I can't comment, so here's a workaround I used: use `cmd.exe` in admin mode for this!

First, type in the following:

```
ftype VimFile="C:\Program Files (x86)\Vim\vim81\gvim.exe" --remote-silent "%1"
```

This ensures that any filetype (extension) associated to the `VimFile` we've set will, by double-click, open in gVim.

Next, choose a file extension (I chose `.vim` and `.tex` for trial) to associate with `VimFile`, and type:

```
assoc .extension=VimFile
```

This associates `.extension` to `VimFile`, and therefore is opened by the `gvim.exe` path we set before.

However, this workaround doesn't work with the `NERDTree` plugin, so I didn't add the option of `--remote-silent "%1"`; bear in mind though that this option only shows the `NERDTree` tree indicating the directory of the file you have chosen to double-click.

Comment: This is very useful. I never know that ftype could be used like this. This really solve my problem. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Actually, you can set vim as your default editor by setting the path of the GVim in your **PATH** variable. For setting of GVim in **PATH** follow [these](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5402776) steps.

You can set any application as default for you. The only thing you have to do is add the application path to the PATH variable.

Comment: You notice that the answer you linked directly contradicts you?

Comment: Here goes a direct quote from the referred link: "Adding Gvim to your `PATH` doesn't make Gvim the default editor for a certain file type." ==> adding the GVim path to the **PATH** variable only makes `gvim` callable.